# Parsing URL through Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, web-scraping, url-parsing

I need to parse

http://www.webpagetest.org/breakdown.php?test=150325_34_0f581da87c16d5aac4ecb7cd07cda921&run=2&cached=0

If you view source of the above url you will find

**Expected Output**:

```
fvRequests= css
fvRequests=7
```

Comment: fvRequests.setValue(0, 0, 'css')
fvRequests.setValue(0, 1, 7)
fvBytes.setValue(0, 0, 'css')
fvBytes.setValue(0, 1, 110557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
import urllib2



if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'http://www.webpagetest.org/breakdown.php?test=150325_34_0f581da87c16d5aac4ecb7cd07cda921&run=2&cached=0'

    # http request
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    response.close()

    # finding values in html
    results = re.findall(r'fvRequests\.setValue\(\d+, \d+, \'?(.*?)\'?\);', html)
    keys = results[::2]
    values = results[1::2]

    # creating a dictionary
    output = dict(zip(keys, values))

    print output
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to locate the script with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and use regular expression pattern to find the the `fvRequests.setValue()` calls and extract the value of the third argument:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


pattern = re.compile(r"fvRequests\.setValue\(\d+, \d+, '?(\w+)'?\);")

response = requests.get("http://www.webpagetest.org/breakdown.php?test=150325_34_0f581da87c16d5aac4ecb7cd07cda921&run=2&cached=0")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

script = soup.find("script", text=lambda x: x and "fvRequests.setValue" in x).text
print(re.findall(pattern, script))
```

Prints:

```
[u'css', u'7', u'flash', u'0', u'font', u'0', u'html', u'14', u'image', u'80', u'js', u'35', u'other', u'14']
```

---

You can go further and pack the list into a dict (solution taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639828/771848)):

```
dict(zip(*([iter(data)] * 2)))
```

which would produce:

```
{
    'image': '80', 
    'flash': '0', 
    'js': '35', 
    'html': '14',  
    'font': '0', 
    'other': '14', 
    'css': '7'
}
```